# StopPropagation will always work on elements that belongs to the same father?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I have an `<aside>` with a menu inside.
Mouse entering and leaving closing and opening the menu. I got an outside element that is positioned absolute over the menu. it is outside of the aside dom. Preventing its bubbling while entering & leaving it doesn't do any effect.

I thought I will prevent bubbling to the document, so it will still catch, but it seems like it doesn't. it seems that the stoppedBubble element needs to be nested inside the aside.

Am I right?
Thank you!

**>>>> EDIT >>>>**

[I have created a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/pXgPG/7) to demonstrate the question.

First example is taken from [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5%3a_Event_Propagation). Second is my addition.

I already got the answer. I can cancel bubbling **only if I stand inside** the scope of the listening element. I cannot cancelBubble/stopPropagation **from outside**.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question what your page structure is and what behavior you do (or don't) want.

Comment: Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/pXgPG/7/
First example is taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation. Second is my addition.

I already got the answer, that I can cancel bubbling up only if I stand on the way towards the listening to event element. **I cannot** cancelBubble/stopPropagation outside.